# How to add a label to a target in Prometheus using Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-webflux, micrometer

I'm trying to add a label to a target in Prometheus modifying files in SpringBoot.

I tried adding a Prometheus label in Springboot the way below (modifying `application.yml` in SpringBoot), but it didn't work.

```yaml
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      application: ${spring.application.name}
      threadLimitInPrometheus: 40 # This tag didn't work
```

Could you let me know any way to add a Prometheus label in SpringBoot?

I know there is a way to add a new label to a target modifying `prometheus.yml` the way below

```yaml
- target_label: "foo"
  replacement: "bar"
```

However, I'd like to find ways in SpringBoot, not Prometheus.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to define tags.

**Common tags could be defined in `application.yml`**

```
management:
  metrics:
    tags:
      key2: value2
```

In case it doesn't work make sure that configuration is applied. You can run your service locally and use `http://localhost:<port>/actuator/prometheus` to check exposed metrics.

As an alternative you can
**use `MeterRegistryCustomizer`**

```
@Configuration
public class MeterRegistryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return (registry) -> registry.config().commonTags("key2", "value2");
    }
}
```

If you need to **define tags for specific metrics only**, use `MeterFilter`

```
@Bean
public MeterFilter customMeterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
            if (id.getName().contains("name")) {
                return id.withTag(Tag.of("key3", "value3"));
            }
            return id;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for answering. The first option just right worked. It looks like I tested it wrong before. And Can I ask one more question?
Is it possible to use Prometheus tag to make a Prometheus Query?  

  
For instance, The query below is the result after making `threadLimit` tag.
`jvm_gc_overhead_percent{application="my-server", instance="my-instance", job="my-server", threadLimit="40"}`. 


I would like to find a way to use `threadLimit` above to make a query like this. 
  
`jvm_gc_overhead_percent  > threadLimit`

Comment: @Astrid typically labels are used to filter metrics. Not sure it's possible in PromQL but you can try to leverage `label_values` function available in Grafana and define a variable like `label_values({application="my-server", instance="my-instance", job="my-server"}, threadLimit)` and then use it in the query `jvm_gc_overhead_percent > $threadLimit` . 

as an alternative you can report `threadLimit` as a custom metric and then use it like `jvm_gc_overhead_percent  > threadLimit`